# Conditional CSS with some access restrictions

Tags: css

I have an implementation with the following content:

```
<body class='theme-dark'>
   <div style=‘???’ id='light'>The theme is light</div>
   <div style=‘???’ id='dark'>The theme is dark</div>
</body>
```

I need a pure-css solution to show either the first of the second `div` based on the `class` of `body` ('theme-light' or 'theme-dark').

I don't have direct access to the `body` element, and javascript is blocked. I can only style the `div` elements individually, no access to document-wide style.

How I can apply some sort of "conditional CSS" directly to the `div` elements, based on the class of body? CSS preprocessors are not an option, btw.

More details about the scenario: this is an application that generates a HTML document and allow the user to insert elements of type DIV. style sections are not allowed neither javascript events. I want to present the data in a different style based on the HTML’s theme (body class).

Comment: I think what you're after is pretty simple: ```.x .y {}```.That will apply styles to any element with a class of "y" that has a parent with a class of "x".

Comment: `parent` is not the crrect term here, it's `ancestor`.

Comment: If by "pure CSS" you mean in a stylesheet, what's stopping you from writing the appropriate selectors? Do you just not know how to write the selectors? Or is there some other restriction, e.g. do you not know the names of the body classes in advance? I don't see why direct access to the body element is necessary here.

Comment: The restriction is that I cannot syle the body element. i am looking for a way to apply a style directly to the divs based on body’s classname

Comment: CSS has no ‘parent’ selector. Your question is ambiguous; you mention having knowledge of the body element class, so I don’t underhand why you can’t use it in your selector?

Comment: I know how the body class is marked. However, I cannot syle the body by myself. i can only compose its innerHTML.

Comment: Why do u need that anyway?

Comment: OP refuses to understand that he's been given the correct answer hours ago. I don't see how we can do more.

Comment: If you dont know you dont understand the use-case, please let others try to do it. This is a restricted scenario, as the question mentions, and I dont have access to the whole DOM, only to the tags mentioned.

Comment: As per your restrictions, your goals cannot be achieved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the task cannot be solved according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Javascript part of the code is only for demonstrating the code example here. I switched into classes `light` and `dark` because using `id` would limit to **one element per page** with any given id since `id` values must be unique.

```js
themeToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('theme-dark')
  document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('theme-light')
})
```

```css
.theme-dark .light {
  display: none;
}

.theme-light .dark {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="theme-dark">
  <div class="light">The theme is light</div>
  <div class="dark">The theme is dark</div>
  <button type="button" id="themeToggle">
    Switch to 
    <span class="light">dark</span>
    <span class="dark">light</span>
  </button>
</body>
```

If you have no access to the HTML and must stick with id, this is how you do the CSS:

```css
.theme-dark #light {
  display: none;
}

.theme-light #dark {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Notice the OP is using `id`, not `class` attributes for `light` and `dark`.

Comment: I have accounted for that.

Comment: As mentioned, I cannot style the body element

Comment: The solution doesn't require that. Read the first sentence of the answer, man.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straightforward really, just use the hierarchical nature of CSS as follows:

```
.theme-dark #light {
    display: none;
}

.theme-light #dark {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned, I cannot style the body element

Comment: You’re not styling the body element. The body element is part of the selector here?

Comment: @BenM Please look at the ??? part. That’s the place where I can put the style rather than a <style> section.

Comment: Why on earth do you have to use style attributes? Why not just add a style tag that uses the selectors you’ve been provided. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @BenM, this is because the application removes all the forbidden tags (like style)